# The performance to handle key up/down on cobalt browser

Tags: cobalt

I tried cobalt browser on our platform (arm-v8 linux), and I found the key response is a little bit slow. When pressing up/down key on the youtube home page, it takes 200ms-400ms from InjectKeyboardEvent to DoLayoutAndProduceRenderTree, and DoLayoutAndProduceRenderTree takes 100ms-150ms then starts to render. I saw movie rows start drawing after 500ms. Any suggestion for this?

I tried to change javascript_engine from mozjs to javascriptcore, but the performance was similar. (I found javascriptcore not enable JIT by default?) Also we run cobalt PC version, and the key response is similar, delayed some time then start scrolling.

Does Cobalt has any performance measurement for developers to check this? how to enable it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you running either `qa` or `gold` builds? `debug` and `devel` will be much slower.

Comment: Yes we use 'debug' version now. It is really faster when I use 'gold' version! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-`gold` builds of Cobalt have a "debug console" HUD that can be used to display live-updating debug values, including performance measurements. `qa` is the fastest build type that still has the debug console.

The debug console HUD can be enabled with the `--debug_console=hud` command-line flag, or toggled at runtime by pressing `Ctrl-O`. 
The HUD is an overlay that displays a bunch of "CVals" (console values). These can be shown or hidden in the debug console itself (type `help`). In particular, you probably want to enable `Event.Duration.MainWebModule` which will be updated every time you hit a key. Take a look at `src/cobalt/browser/web_module_stat_tracker.cc` for a description of the event-timing CVals.

There is also a build target `layout_benchmarks` that tests the non-Javascript portions of a full layout. This is not quite the same as an incremental layout, and clearly Javascript (InjectKeyboardEvent) is a majority of your key-handling cost, but it may be a decent proxy for overall performance, and is reasonably comparable between platforms.

JavaScriptCore will soon be deprecated in favor of SpiderMonkey (a.k.a. mozjs), and removed from the Cobalt tree, so it's not an avenue of exploration with much future.

*Note that Linux X11 Cobalt is not necessarily as fast as device platforms, as the X11 implementation is not particularly optimized. MesaGL is software-rendered, for example. Video composition is done fairly crudely, and YUV conversion is also done on the CPU.*